# Is it possible to change an initialized variable in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I was doing an exercise to count the even digits in a number. This is the program.

```
count_even(Number, 1) :-
  Number < 10,
  even(Number).

count_even(Number, 0) :-
  Number < 10,
  odd(Number).

count_even(Number, Count) :-
  Number >= 10,
  split_number(Number, Digit, NewNumber),
  count_even(NewNumber, NumCount),
  DigCount is mod(Digit + 1, 2),
  Count is NumCount + DigCount.

split_number(Number, Digit, NewNumber) :-
  Digit is mod(Number, 10),
  NewNumber is Number//10.

even(Number) :-
  0 is mod(Number, 2).

odd(Number) :-
  1 is mod(Number, 2).
```

Now I wondered if it was really necessary to have a NumCount in the third count_even. What if I change the code of the third count_even to

```
count_even(Number, Count) :-
  Number >= 10,
  split_number(Number, Digit, NewNumber),
  count_even(NewNumber, Count),
  DigCount is mod(Digit + 1, 2),
  Count is Count + DigCount.
```

Now the program won't do its job anymore because `Count is Count + DigCount` will fail if `DigCount` is equal to 1. My question is if something like this is possible. Is it possible to force `Count is Count + DigCount` to be executed like in a C# or Java language? That is, just do the calculation and don't see it as a rule in case `Count` is instantiated?

Comment: No. `Count is Count + DigCount` is equivalent to `Count =:= Count + DigCount`. In *Prolog*, that is. :) there is [`nb_setarg`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nb_setarg/3) and [`nb_setval`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nb_setval/2) though...

Comment: please do not use prolog as an imperative language. In truth there are no 'programming vars' in prolog that you can initialize, but logical vars that you can unify.

Comment: There's no reason to reuse `Count` in this context. Why not call `count_even(NewNumber, Count1)` then do `Count is Count1 + DigCount`?

Comment: @rano I'm trying real hard. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Since Prolog vars can be unified or ununified and that can lead to easily assume that it strictly means that unification is instantiation and leads to believe that you can `set` again the value of a var by unifying it again or by not considering it a logical var in a logical formula to be proven true (like in your case).

It is true that there are some tricks, like Will Ness said, that in the form of some meta predicates let you manipulate the language compunds (since prolog is an [homoiconic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity)) but they are not ISO, they are implementation dependent, and above all they are like a cannon to shoot flies in this case.

Maybe someone else will have some better suggestion on how to try to interpret logic constructs as means to achieve imperative languages results, I will point you to the interpretation of an Horn logical clause as an imperative procedure [by Kowalski](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~rak/papers/Chapter5.pdf).

Comment: Also, it is possible to [automatically translate imperative algorithms into Prolog](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.212.5370&rep=rep1&type=pdf) using [Constraint Handling Rules](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chr).